# Layout problems in a resource file

Tags: android, formatting, rendering, adapter, display

I have installed Java SDK and Android Studio 3.5.3 - set The target device and the Android OS as Pie.
I have a simple form with some constrained controls but no code behind at present.
When I run the project - I get the warning shown attached and when the form is rendered in the emulator the formatting of the controls is wrong (see design view image)....?

I have tried to update the drivers for the display adapter but it reports they are at current version.
Any ideas I am getting this issue?
Thanks in advance
[image: AndroidRenderingIssue]

Here is the code behind activitiy_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="175dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="569dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="650dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR"
        android:textColor="#9C27B0"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="500dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml code

Comment: That warning doesn't have anything to do with the UI

Comment: I posted the warning dialog because I wasnt sure if it DID have something to do with the problem I am seeing, that is all. I wanted to be specific providing as much information as possible in order for assistance...

Comment: There might be some problem with your code so please share it

Comment: What kind of result you want?

Comment: I expect the emulator display to appear as it is designed on the left !.. why has the constrained formatting been ignored and the controls simply shown at the top of the screen...?

Comment: @Guido where do you want to add switch?

Comment: I have.. a switch control.. I was simply playing around with some controls on the form. Why would that be a problem..?

Comment: Was about to post this but saw its already been answered leaving this as comment anyway.
Its because you are not setting the correct constraints for your widgets.
Lines like these ```tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="650dp"``` only affect what you see on the editor during designtime and not in actual runtime on the device or emulator. For that you need to set proper constraints.

The IDE should also be showing you errors as that @qki's answer mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it this way, there are benefits like lesser attributes and easy to understand code

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR"
        android:textColor="#9C27B0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Switch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="100dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments... I simply used the design editor to generate the code. Are suggesting writing XML by hand...?

Comment: Yes, that would be more proper way to design your screens

Comment: But this answer changes the ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout, it doesn't answer the question asked (which is why ConstraintLayout is not working), or am I missing something?

Comment: The code should be more readable and understandable, it doesn't matter which layout you use

Answer (score 0):

Some of Your Views or Buttons did not have constraints, so they would jump to (0,0) at runtime. Here is the proper xml code

You could clearly read it from Warnings (red icon)

In Constraint Layout it is critical to add constraints to all your controls because they would just jump to (0,0) if not, which can later broke next control etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="175dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:text="RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR"
    android:textColor="#9C27B0"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchMode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Switch"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewTitle" />
```